# Multipart File Upload Request Using Unirest in Java

Tags: java, post, file-upload, multipart, unirest

I am able to post this request using a REST client (Insomnia). However, when I unable to write a proper code to do the same in Java. Below is how my insomnia request looks like.

[image]

Below is how the code generated by the Client looks like.

```
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("http://172.16.6.15:5053/image-service/services/image-panel-service/panel/images?=")
  .header("com.yatra.tenant.header.tenantid", "1051")
  .header("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001")
  .body("-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"imageFile\"\r\n\r\n")
  .asString();
```

Below is the code I have written in Java which doesn't work.

```
try {
            HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("http://172.16.6.15:5053/image-service/services/image-panel-service/panel/images")
            .header("com.yatra.tenant.header.tenantid", "1051")
            .header("content-type", "multipart/form-data")
            .field("imageFile", new File("Desert.jpg"))
            .field("imageData", new File("ImageUploadRequest.json")).asString();

            System.out.println(response.getBody());

        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Snippet from their documentation
http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/#file-uploads

```
 Unirest.post("http://httpbin.org")
   .field("imageFile", new File("JellyFirst.jpg"))
   .asEmpty();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
try {
    MultipartBody body = Unirest.post("http://localhost:4849/upload/images")
        .field("name", "bingoo.txt")
        .field("files", temp1)
        .field("files", temp2)
        .field("files", temp3);
    HttpResponse<String> file = body.asString();
    System.out.println(file.getStatus());

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

snippet from https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.mashape.unirest.request.body.MultipartBody